# No population? How to answer such question?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, binomial-distribution

Say the givens are:
probability of a battery being defective is = 0.40
being not defective = 0.60
STD = 1.5 hours
mean = 7.5 hours

The question states: if 5 batteries are randomly selected what is the probability that none of them are defective?

ps: forgive me for any mistakes
my approach: 
 if i tried binomial distribution then i will need n or the population (so i cant). and if i did 0.40 times 5 i will get 2 which is not the answer.

which confuses me how to solve such a question?

Comment: This appears to be a standard binomial probability problem.  You are asked to find the probability of 0 successes when there are 5 trials (5 is your n) and the probability of "success" is 0.4.  There is a specific binomial probability formula where these numbers can be plugged in.

Comment: Please include the `self-study` tag if this is for an assignment/test.

Comment: n is given in the question; it's not the size of the population (the notional population of batteries wouldn't have a known size but in this case is very very large - that may as well be infinite), it's the number of batteries

Comment: What do "hours" have to do with the probability of a battery being defective? It looks like, as already pointed out in the answer, you just have to either calculate the probability of a Binomial(5,0.4) being 0 or that of a Binomial(5, 0.6) being 5!

Answer (score 1):

This has been here for a while. I'll answer it because it is an important type of problem. Some day soon, something similar may find its way onto an exam.

The mean and standard deviation (in hours) do not seem relevant to the particular part of the problem you posted. (They seem to be there to see if you can sort
out what is needed and what is not. Or possibly for
another part of the problem you did not show.)

The number $X$ of defective batteries out of 5 selected. Its distribution is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 5,\, p = .4).$ (So the relevant information is the probability that each battery is bad and the number of batteries chosen.) You seek 
$$P(X = 0) = {5 \choose 0}p^0(1-p)^5 = 
1(.4^0)(1-.4)^6\\ = (1-.4)^5 =.6^5 = 0.07776.$$

You could get the same answer using R statistical software (in which `dbinom` is a binomial PDF) as follows:

```
dbinom(0, 5, .4)
[1] 0.07776
```

*Notes:* (1) Sometimes it is helpful to approximate binomial probabilities by using a normal distribution. This is not a good problem for using a normal approximation, and besides that, it is easy just to find the exact binomial probability.

(2) Without explicitly mentioning a binomial distribution, you
could say that you want $5$ *good* batteries, when
you sample batteries independently. Then you can use the multiplication rule for independent events to get:

$$P(\text{All 6 G}) = P(\text{1st G})P(\text{2nd G})\times\cdots\times P(\text{5th G})
= (.6)^5.$$